# How to restore symmetric key on the new database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, encryption

I have an issue with symmetric key restoring on the another database.
I have table in the first(old) database with encrypted column.(The table contains encrypted data)
The key in the old database has been created with the next sql script:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'TESTPSWD'
GO
CREATE CERTIFICATE [CertificateSecurity] WITH SUBJECT = 'Key Protection';
GO
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY [EncryptKey] WITH
    ALGORITHM = AES_256 
    ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE [CertificateSecurity]
GO
```

And now I have to move this table with all data to the new database.
I import table with data from the old database.
And there is a question: Is there any way to create the same encryption key in the new database without specifying key_source and the identity_value? (Because I don't have it)
I tried to create it with the same sql query as above, but decryption in this case returns NULL.

**P.S.** I know what I can decrypt data then recreate key(with all parammeters supplied) and encrypt data with a new key.But it would be great to find another solution.

Comment: I have got the answer to this question here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65531/how-to-restore-symmetric-key-on-the-new-database .

Answer (score 0):

as far as am concerned, the symmetric key is a securable at the database level, and usually is considered with its database where was created in.

note: a symmetric key only decrypts the data encrypted by itself, so by deleting an existing symmetric key, you will lose access to your data encrypted by deleted symmetric key.

to avoid such problems, usually we create database backup which contains all available symmetric keys. and if you lost your symmetric key, restoring the database backup will retrieve all keys again.